# jQuery mouseover and mouse out for slideshow

Tags: jquery, mouseover

The following script works fine however I would like the arrows (#leftControl #rightControl) to be hidden and then appear when you hover the slideshow. The thing is that if we are on the first slide only the right arrow needs to appear and viceversa, this is to avoid giving the option to make the slideshow sliding left or right if there is nothing to see.

```
 // manageControls: Hides and Shows controls depending on currentPosition
 function manageControls(position){
// Hide left arrow if position is first slide
if(position==0){ $('#leftControl').hide() } else{ $('#leftControl').show() }
// Hide right arrow if position is last slide
if(position==numberOfSlides-1){ $('#rightControl').hide() } else{  $('#rightControl').show() }
}
```

[full script](http://jsfiddle.net/asWeb/EsGLn/49/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function manageControls(position){

$('#slide_container').mouseenter(function(){
        // Hide left arrow if position is first slide
        if(position==0){ 
                $('#leftControl').hide(); 
        } else { 
                $('#leftControl').show();
        }
        // Hide right arrow if position is last slide
        if(position==numberOfSlides-1){ 
                $('#rightControl').hide(); 
        } else{  
                $('#rightControl').show();
        }
});

$('#slide_container').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#leftControl').fadeOut();
        $('#rightControl').fadeOut();
});

}
```

Comment: it doesn't work smoothly when you hover one of the arrows they appear and disappear quickly http://jsfiddle.net/asWeb/EsGLn/73/

Comment: okay - maybe try to change `mouseover`to `mouseenter`and `mouseout`to `mouseleave`. Tell me if that works! (I changed it in my answer)

Comment: Excellent it works now, I had to add the following "$('#leftControl').hide(); " to avoid having the left arrow appearing as soon as the page would load. It's now actually precise when you hover it, much better then using mouseOver. Thanks :)

Comment: hi there, unfortunately I found a bug. If I keep scrolling and the slides is the last one either on the left or right it keeps scrolling and the arrow does not disappear :( I am working on it though :)